# Does concavity put restrictions on whether the 2nd derivative is nonincreasing/nondecreasing.

Tags: functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

In other words, can we have something like a concave function where the second derivative is increasing over some range and then decreasing over another range?

---

Edit: What if the concave function is strictly increasing? (or decreasing?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $f(x)=-e^{x^{2}}$ is such a function.

Comment: Thank you. Any chance there is an obvious example with an increasing, concave function, that you know of? (your example has the second derivative go from increasing to decreasing when the functions goes from increasing to decreasing. Other examples I have come up with -- such as $Ln[x^2]$ -- also have this property...